# How Can I Get These Two Event Handlers to Work Together?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, chess, chessboard.js

I am creating a chess opening trainer using [cm-chessboard](https://github.com/shaack/cm-chessboard) and [chess.js](https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js/). The idea is that sequential chess positions are extracted from the Lichess Opening Explorer API and the player tests themselves by moving the next best move and/or answering questions on the names of the openings.

However, I've got myself into a bit of a pickle.

Currently, it only questions the user on the computer's turn. I can't work out a way to get it to wait for the user to press the return key before revealing the answer about the player's move.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chess Opening Trainer</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1.0"/>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://alftheelf.github.io/Chess-Opening-Trainer/cm-chessboard/styles/cm-chessboard.css"/> 
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chess.js/0.10.2/chess.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">

        body{font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}

        .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 0.6fr;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr;
        gap: 0px 0px;
        }

        .board {
            grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3;
            width: 800px;
            max-width: 800px;
        }
        #interface { 
            grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3; 
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: thin;
            width: 400px;
            max-width: 400px;
        }

        p{
            width: 100%;
            align: center;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="board" id="board"></div>
  <div id="interface">
      <span id="prompt"></span>
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">


//SETTINGS

var side = 'black' //select which side to play as
var rating = '1600';
var realistic = true;
var limit = 50;


//Define initial variables

var state = null;
var moveCount = 0;
if (side == 'black') {var notSide = 'white'} else{var notSide = 'black'}
var positionAnswer
var bestMove
var opponentMove
var PGN


//define functions

var addEvent = document.addEventListener ? function(target,type,action){
    if(target){
        target.addEventListener(type,action,false);
    }
} : function(target,type,action){
    if(target){
        target.attachEvent('on' + type,action,false);
    }
}

addEvent(document,'keydown',function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if(key===13){ //Press the return key
        keypress()
    }
});

function keypress(){
    if (state == 'questionPosition') { //Then reveal the answer

        document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = positionAnswer;

        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = positionAnswer + "<br><br>key) What is " + side + "\'s best move?"
            state = "questionBestMove";
        }, 500)
    }
}


</script>

<script type="module">
    
    import {INPUT_EVENT_TYPE, COLOR, Chessboard, MARKER_TYPE} from "https://alftheelf.github.io/Chess-Opening-Trainer/cm-chessboard/src/cm-chessboard/Chessboard.js"
    import {BORDER_TYPE} from "https://alftheelf.github.io/Chess-Opening-Trainer/cm-chessboard/src/cm-chessboard/Chessboard.js"

    const chess = new Chess() //Creates a new Chess() object. Add a FEN string as an argument to start from a FEN.

    function inputHandler(event) {
        console.log("event", event)
        event.chessboard.removeMarkers(undefined, MARKER_TYPE.dot)


        //Before move. Clicking about, and showing dot for possible moves and such.
        if (event.type === INPUT_EVENT_TYPE.moveStart) {
            const moves = chess.moves({square: event.square, verbose: true});
            for (const move of moves) {
                event.chessboard.addMarker(move.to, MARKER_TYPE.dot)
            }
            return moves.length > 0

        //Here is once a move has been attempted    
        } else if (event.type === INPUT_EVENT_TYPE.moveDone) {

            if (state == "questionBestMove") {

                const move = {from: event.squareFrom, to: event.squareTo} //gets which move was attempted from event
                const result = chess.move(move) //gets result of move

                bestMove = PGN[moveCount];

                if (result){
                    if (result.san == bestMove.san) {

                        moveCount += 1;

                        event.chessboard.disableMoveInput()
                        event.chessboard.setPosition(chess.fen())

                        document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = "";

                        //Here is where I need it to ask a question if the bestMove.name is not null.

                        opponentMove = PGN[moveCount];
                        positionAnswer = PGN[moveCount].name;
                        moveCount += 1;

                        setTimeout(() => { // smoother with 500ms delay
                            chess.move({from: opponentMove.uci.slice(0,2), to: opponentMove.uci.slice(2,4)})
                            event.chessboard.enableMoveInput(inputHandler, side[0])
                            event.chessboard.setPosition(chess.fen())

                            if (positionAnswer){
                                document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = "event) What position is this?";
                                state = 'questionPosition';
                            }else{
                                document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = "key) What is " + side + "\'s best move?"
                            }

                        }, 500)

                    }else{
                        console.warn("That move is not the answer")
                        chess.undo();
                        event.chessboard.setPosition(chess.fen());
                    }
                    return result
                

                } else { //If result returns null, then we will loop back to the begining of the function to have another go with new dots.
                    console.warn("invalid move", move)
                }
                return result
            }
        }
    }

    // The PGN is inputted manually here. Normally this would be extracted from the Lichess API.
    if (side == 'black') {
    
        PGN = [
            {uci: "e2e4", san: "e4", name: "King's Pawn"},
            {uci: "e7e5", san: "e5", name: "King's Pawn Game"},
            {uci: "g1f3", san: "Nf3", name: "King's Knight Opening"},
            {uci: "b8c6", san: "Nc6", name: "King's Knight Opening: Normal Variation"},
            {uci: "f1b5", san: "Bb5", name: "Ruy Lopez"},
            {uci: "a7a6", san: "a6", name: "Ruy Lopez: Morphy Defense"},
            {uci: "b5c6", san: "Bxc6", name: "Ruy Lopez: Exchange Variation"},
            {uci: "d7c6", san: "dxc6", name: null},
            {uci: "b1c3", san: "Nc3", name: "Ruy Lopez: Exchange Variation, Keres Variation"},
            {uci: "f7f6", san: "f6", name: null},
            {uci: "e1g1", san: "O-O", name: null}
        ]
    }else{

        PGN = [
            {uci: "e2e4", san: "e4", name: "King's Pawn"},
            {uci: "e7e5", san: "e5", name: "King's Pawn Game"},
            {uci: "g1f3", san: "Nf3", name: "King's Knight Opening"},
            {uci: "b8c6", san: "Nc6", name: "King's Knight Opening: Normal Variation"},
            {uci: "f1b5", san: "Bb5", name: "Ruy Lopez"},
            {uci: "a7a6", san: "a6", name: "Ruy Lopez: Morphy Defense"},
            {uci: "b5a4", san: "Ba4", name: null},
            {uci: "b7b5", san: "b5", name: "Ruy Lopez: Morphy Defense, Caro Variation"},
            {uci: "a4b3", san: "Bb3", name: null},
            {uci: "g8f6", san: "Nf6", name: null},
            {uci: "e1g1", san: "O-O", name: null}
        ]
    }

    console.log('PGN', PGN)

    if (side == 'white'){
        const board = new Chessboard(document.getElementById("board"), {
            position: chess.fen(),
            sprite: {url: "https://alftheelf.github.io/Chess-Opening-Trainer/cm-chessboard/assets/images/chessboard-sprite-staunty.svg"},
            style: {moveMarker: MARKER_TYPE.square, hoverMarker: undefined},
            orientation: COLOR.white
        })
        state = 'questionBestMove';
        document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = "What is " + side + "\'s best move?";
        board.enableMoveInput(inputHandler, COLOR.white)
    }
    else{
        const board = new Chessboard(document.getElementById("board"), {
            position: chess.fen(),
            sprite: {url: "https://alftheelf.github.io/Chess-Opening-Trainer/cm-chessboard/assets/images/chessboard-sprite-staunty.svg"},
            style: {moveMarker: MARKER_TYPE.square, hoverMarker: undefined},
            orientation: COLOR.black
        })


        //Get opponent move and name
        var opponentMove = PGN[moveCount];
        positionAnswer = PGN[moveCount].name;

        moveCount += 1;

        setTimeout(() => { // smoother with 500ms delay
            chess.move({from: opponentMove.uci.slice(0,2), to: opponentMove.uci.slice(2,4)})
            board.enableMoveInput(inputHandler, COLOR.black)
            board.setPosition(chess.fen())
            
            if (positionAnswer){
            
                document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = "What position is this?";
                state = "questionPosition"
            }

        }, 500)

    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've condensed it for this post. Normally, the variable `PNG` is created using the Lichess API, but for this example I've instead defined two games manually, one for black and one for white. I chose examples with some 'null' names in the middle so that I could test whether it's working correctly.

As you can see, I got the opponent position question to wait because it's inside the `keypress()` function. The problem I had with doing the same for the player position question, is that once the question is revealed, the computer needs to make its move automatically. I tried making a move from inside the `keypress()` function but I couldn't get it to work because `event` wasn't defined. I tried somehow trying to pass `event` to `keypress` but it didn't work, and I sure that's not really the best way anyway.

I presume the correct way is to properly organise `inputHandler`. I've rewritten it so many times, but I've never managed to get it working. The logic is confusing me, and I think using my `state = "questionPosition"` idea to separate the game states may be causing more problems than it solves. I wouldn't be surprised if I see that on [r/badcode](https://www.reddit.com/r/badcode/).

I would really appreciate any advice on how to fix this.

This version I have posted is a version that *almost works*, which I thought would be easier to see what's going on than some of the versions I had that followed.

I've also put a live version up at https://alftheelf.github.io/Chess-Opening-Trainer/.

Does anyone know how I could tackle this? I've spent a week trying to fix it, but I just don't know anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to finally get this working.

I ended up renaming `event` in the `inputHander` to `chessEvent` so that it was separate from the `event` in `keypress()`. Then I cloned `chessEvent` and used it in the keypress function. `chess` also had to be make global, along with `inputHandler`, which I achieved by making it a variable.

```
inputHandler1 = function inputHandler(chessEvent) {...
```

Now I can control the board from within `keypress()` and it works perfectly.